# WPF Image Path Blues

Tags: wpf, vb.net

I have a number of images in the resources directory and access them like this...

```
Public Function ReturnToolBarImage(ByVal ImageName As String) As Image
    Dim UpdateImage As New Image
    With UpdateImage
    End With
    Dim UpdateBitmap As New BitmapImage
    With UpdateBitmap
        .BeginInit()
        .UriSource = New Uri("pack://application:,,,/HOA_Manager_Client_04;component/Resources/" & ImageName, UriKind.Absolute)
        .EndInit()
        .DecodePixelHeight = 32
    End With
    UpdateImage.Source = UpdateBitmap
    Return UpdateImage
End Function
```

I have control that insists upon using an Image Path not an Image - I can access it like this

```
.ImageSource = "//application:,,,/HOA_Manager_Client_04;component/Resources/Customers.png"
```

But the image is, or course, far too large.. Soooooo I added a function to save the resized image to a Temp folder (that is working) and send the path back - but for some reason that just doesn't work (no errors, just no image). Any ideas?

```
Public Function ReturnToolBarImageAsString(ByVal ImageName As String) As String
    Dim UpdateImage As New Image
    With UpdateImage
    End With
    Dim UpdateBitmap As New BitmapImage
    With UpdateBitmap
        .BeginInit()
        .UriSource = New Uri("pack://application:,,,/HOA_Manager_Client_04;component/Resources/" & ImageName, UriKind.Absolute)
        .EndInit()
        .DecodePixelHeight = 32
    End With
    Using FS As New IO.FileStream("../../Pages/Temp/" & ImageName, IO.FileMode.Create)
        Dim vEncoder As New PngBitmapEncoder
        vEncoder.Frames.Add(BitmapFrame.Create(UpdateBitmap))
        vEncoder.Save(FS)
    End Using
    'Return "../Temp/" & ImageName
    Return "//application:,,,/HOA_Manager_Client_04;component/Pages/Temp/" & ImageName
End Function
```

Comment: Have you read about pack uris?  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970069.aspx

Comment: Is there any way then to save the image file as a resource?

Comment: Why not just return exactly the path where you save the image, `"../../Pages/Temp/" & ImageName`? That's where the image is, and it will not magically move into embedded resources.

Comment: Hi Clemens - That is what I first tried, but to no avail!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By creating a directory at run time in the Bin directory seems to have cured the issue

```
Public Function ReturnToolBarImageAsString(ByVal ImageName As String) As String
    Dim UpdateImage As New Image
    With UpdateImage
    End With
    Dim UpdateBitmap As New BitmapImage
    With UpdateBitmap
        .BeginInit()
        .DecodePixelHeight = 32
        .UriSource = New Uri("pack://application:,,,/HOA_Manager_Client_04;component/Resources/" & ImageName, UriKind.Absolute)
        .EndInit()
    End With

    Dim vPath As String = My.Application.Info.DirectoryPath
    If Not IO.Directory.Exists(vPath & "\Temp_Images") Then
        IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(vPath & "\Temp_Images")
    End If
    Using FS As New IO.FileStream(vPath & "\Temp_Images\" & ImageName, IO.FileMode.Create)
        Dim vEncoder As New PngBitmapEncoder
        vEncoder.Frames.Add(BitmapFrame.Create(UpdateBitmap))
        vEncoder.Save(FS)
    End Using
    Return vPath & "\Temp_Images\" & ImageName
End Function
```